# Html/Css - (Работа с блоком и текстом)

Tags: html

Вопрос таков: на сайте есть (какой, либо блок) например картинка по центру, квадрат и тд, как только я хочу поставить текст то он ставится по центру напротив картинки, как сделать так чтобы текст вставал отдельно от блока?

(если я правильно понимаю то я где-то наследование поставил)

Можете ли вы, пожалуйста, накидать ссылки на обучение html/css (Где объясняют всё нормально, показывают)

Comment: Приведите код, чтобы можно было понять проблему

Comment: Учу по видео, пишу, разбираюсь (самоучка)

Comment: не вставить так как, больше символом написано

Comment: Прям точно я вас не понял, но наверно вы имели в виду flex/grid, прочитайте на mdn